# View attachments in calendar list

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

When we view item in calendar list and select an event, a pop up appears showing the filled fields with attachments.

Now I don't want to show the fields . My requirement is, when ever user clicks on an event, it should directly open the attachments attached with it .

Comment: could you specifiy a bit more please? What do you mean by event? Your own or SharePoint standard?

is the pop up made by you? If yes can you give code snippets?

The question is hard to answere with proper information of what you current solution ist and what's yours and what is SharePoint standard.

Answer (score 0):

Each item created has an ID associated with it. When an item is clicked, a link like http://SharePointSite:1234/site1/Lists/Calender/DispForm.aspx?ID=1 is invoked, displaying the details of the list item.
The attachment of such a list can be accessed by http://SharePointSite:1234/site1/Lists/Calender/Attachments/1/lake.jpg